# Form fields not blanked on clicking in the field

Tags: html, forms

I have a simple form which is such:

```
<form method="post" action="#" id="contact-form">
                    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="NAME" onfocus="if (this.value == 'NAME') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'NAME';}" required/>
                    <input id="email" type="email" name="email" value="E-MAIL" onfocus="if (this.value == 'E-MAIL ADRESS') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'E-MAIL ADDRESS';}" required />
                    <textarea rows="5" cols="60" id="message" name="message" type="text" style="background:none; color: black;font-family: inherit; font-size: 11px; font-weight: 800;" onfocus="if (this.value == 'YOUR MESSAGE') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'YOUR MESSAGE';}" required>MESSAGE</textarea>
                    <br> </br>
                    <button class="button-outline defalut send-mail" type="submit" name="submit"><strong>Send</strong> Message</button>
    </form>
```

As seen, I have provided for a value to each field. There is a strange problem though, The E-MAIL and the MESSAGE values are not overwritten like they are in the NAME field. Which is to say, on clicking in the NAME field the 'Name' disappears and the field is blank. On clicking the E-MAIL/ MESSAGE field, the text does not disappear and the field is not blanked. Why does this happen? How is it fixed?

The live form can be seen [here](http://54.200.9.8/Ref_HTML/contact.html). The HTML is [here](http://pastebin.com/Bv865sqS). All the files are [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/le0bdfkacqk4wu5/AAASTOw-DZIWOhvrZqkwtZpia?dl=0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` statements are incorrect. You set the value to `E-MAIL` but the `if` statement checks for `E-MAIL ADRESS` (sic). Similarly for the textarea field.

```html
<form method="post" action="#" id="contact-form">
  <input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="NAME" onfocus="if (this.value == 'NAME') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'NAME';}" required/>
  <input id="email" type="email" name="email" value="E-MAIL" onfocus="if (this.value == 'E-MAIL') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'E-MAIL';}" required />
  <textarea rows="5" cols="60" id="message" name="message" type="text" style="background:none; color: black;font-family: inherit; font-size: 11px; font-weight: 800;" onfocus="if (this.value == 'MESSAGE') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'MESSAGE';}"
  required>MESSAGE</textarea>
  <br>
  <button class="button-outline defalut send-mail" type="submit" name="submit"><strong>Send</strong> Message</button>
</form>
```

Here's a [working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/uozsuy1x/).